# Difference between QUESTIONS and Query

Tags: mysql

when i check status from MySQL console it shows `104 questions`, ... and in the MySQL general log it shows `18 Queries` !

Q1 -> what is the difference between Question and Query ?
Q2 -> For a standard site what should be an ideal limit for questions and queries per page [in forum/social networking] ?

Comment: It is absolutely impossible to answer your 2nd question.  You should just do the stuff you need to do as efficiently as possible, using performance tests to check if it still works. Without traffic details, specific code, content breakdown, hardware details etc etc there is no answer possible.

Comment: but i said IDEAL or standard !

Comment: @Sourav: ideal: zero DB-access. Standard: still un-answerable as it depends on **tons** of variables.

Comment: @Sourav - Well in that case, the answer is 42.  Google it if you don't believe me.

Comment: There is no "standard". Your answer would either be "zero" as @joachim-sauer said, or "as much as you need to get your data, but not so much that your site runs slow.

Comment: okz, but what about my first question ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Queries):

> **Queries.** The number of statements executed by the server. This variable includes statements executed within stored programs, unlike the Questions variable. It does not count COM_PING or COM_STATISTICS commands. This variable was added in MySQL 5.0.76.
>
> **Questions.** The number of statements executed by the server. As of MySQL 5.0.72, this includes only statements sent to the server by clients and no longer includes statements executed within stored programs, unlike the Queries variable. This variable does not count COM_PING, COM_STATISTICS, COM_STMT_PREPARE, COM_STMT_CLOSE, or COM_STMT_RESET commands.